# slideToggle is creating a wobble at the end of an accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Creating an accordion - on the slide - the elements underneath the element that is sliding seem to move down a px and then back up, creating a juddering effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Promos banners rotation and accordion
$(function(){
    var $accordionList = $('.accordion').find('li');
    var numberOfItems = $accordionList.length;
    var currentItem = 0;

    // Set first item to active
    $accordionList.eq(currentItem).addClass('active').find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {});

    // Loops through promos
    var infiniateLoop = setInterval(function() {

        if(currentItem == numberOfItems - 1){
            currentItem = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentItem++;
        }

        // Remove active class, if is has it, and close content
        $accordionList.parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active')
            .find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {
        });

        // Add active class and open content
        $accordionList.eq(currentItem).addClass('active').find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {
        });

    }, 4000 );

    // Click to show promo
    $accordionList.on('click', function () {
        // Stop rotation
        clearInterval(infiniateLoop);

        var $accordionHead = $(this);

        // Remove active class, if is has it, and close content
        if($accordionHead.hasClass('active')) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else {
            $accordionHead.parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active')
                .find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {
            });

            // Add active class and open content
            $accordionHead.addClass('active').find('.content').slideToggle(800, function() {
            });
        };
    });
});

});
```

[Fiddle here demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/chrism/6tmL3/3/)

I've seen some suggestions that you fix the height of the content div - but the site is responsive so that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, I've had this problem before to. My favorite fix is to just make my own `.slideToggle()`

```
div = $('div');
height = div.height();
width = div.width();

$('div').click( function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
    $(this).animate({height: "0", width: "0"}, 200).hide().addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $(this).animate({height: height, width: width}, 200).show().removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

You could even wrap it in a prototype function if you wanted to.